# In basketball, when the ball hits the bottom of the net, wraps around and goes in the right way,. Does it count? Or violation?

Tags: rules, basketball

If it hits the bottom of the net and the ball gets caught up and rolls around and goes in down through the rim the correct way, is this a counted basket.  To clarify, the ball never goes through the bottom of the rim up the wrong way, it is caught in the net below the rim but wraps around to enter the top.